# [MySQL][ODBC 1.4(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.12 mongosqld v2.14.5]parse sql 'UPDATE

Tags: sql, mongodb, odbc, mongodb-biconnector, mongosqld

I am trying to use MongoDB ODBC driver to update an asset into the database. Currently, I am using Power Automate and here is my code that is not working (select statment is working fine):

Connect String:

```
Provider=MSDASQL;Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties="DSN=TEST2;SERVER=20.126.XX.XXX;UID={powerautomateuser?source=XXXXX-ro-db};DATABASE={XXXXX-ro-db};PORT=33XX;LOG_QUERY=1;"
```

Execute SQL:

```
UPDATE powerAutomatePosts 
SET facebookPostld = '195982166685423' 
WHERE _id = '646d9c2a9ad6287f1ccfa760';
```

Error:

vCorrelation Id: 67dd3281-804a-4df2-9c26-f503340be92f

ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 1.4(w) Driver][mysqld-5.7.12 mongosqld v2.14.5]parse sql 'UPDATE powerAutomatePosts
SET facebookPostld = '195982166685423'
WHERE _id = '646d9c2a9ad6287f1ccfa760';' error: unexpected UPDATE at position 8 near UPDATE

To update the asset into the MongoDB

Comment: Are you sure the ODBC driver supports UPDATE operation at all? Perhaps it provides only SELECT statements.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for that error, found that maybe is the character encoding, as saying this [link](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/ODBC-Problem-with-mongoDB-BI-connector-MySQL/m-p/378673#M16237)

Try changing the unicode driver you're using on the ODBC configuration. Hope this can help you